# Pandas select data range

Tags: python, pandas

Relatively new with Panda and Python--and I'm probably missing something in my syntax.  I'm looking to select a data range in a data set:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("2020_Transactions_v03.txt", delimiter="|")
df1["Transaction Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Transaction Date"])
start_date = '2020-03-01'
end_date = '2020-04-01'
mask = (df1['Transaction Date'] > start_date) & (df1("Transaction Date") <= end_date)
print(df1.loc[mask])
```

This isn't really working as I expected (filtering only the dates that I needed to convert the data type in the first place). Any ideas on how to select only the dates within the mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your `2020_Transactions_v03.txt` file looks like, so I created my own `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

# my own dataframe
dates = ['2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Transaction Date':dates})

start_date = '2020-04-01'
end_date = '2020-04-03'

# filtering
df_filtered = df[(df['Transaction Date'] > start_date) & (df['Transaction Date'] < end_date)]
print(df_filtered)


# output:
# Transaction Date
# 1    2020-04-02
```